robot_localization GeographicLib::GeographicErr
I am trying to run a ros2 bag recorded in gazebo through the robot_localization package. However, for the same trajectory, sometimes, I get an error saying -
[navsat_transform_node-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘GeographicLib::GeographicErr’
[navsat_transform_node-3]  what(): Easting -5.98693e+11km not in UTM range for N hemisphere [0km, 1000km]
[ERROR] [navsat_transform_node-3]: process has died [pid 1684, exit code -6, cmd ‘/opt/ros/humble/lib/robot_localization/navsat_transform_node --ros-args -r __node:=navsat_transform_node --params-file /tmp/launch_params_u_kh4zrf -r /imu/data:=/imu -r /gps/fix:=/fix’].

The package works perfectly most of the times, but sometimes, it throws the above error for the same kind of ros2 bags it worked earlier for. I would appreciate any lead on the cause behind this. Thank you!

geographiclib source code says UTM eastings are allowed to be in the range [0km, 1000km], northings are allowed to be in in [0km, 9600km] for the northern hemisphere and in [900km, 10000km] for the southern hemisphere. [...] So the actual limits on the northings are [-9100km, 9600km] for the "northern" hemisphere and [900km, 19600km] for the "southern" hemisphere.) which is why it throws the error. Has something to do with converting UTM or UPS coordinate to geographic coordinates.

Please include your full config, as well as a sample message from every input. I would also recommend recording a bag of the data to see if you can reproduce by stepping through the bag. That will let you isolate the message that causes the error.
